# Property 'x' does not exist on type 'y'

Tags: typescript, next.js

Why typescript informed me that:
Property 'dateTime' does not exist on type 'SSRPageProps'.ts(2339)

Bellow my code, I see that data-time is typed.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";

export default function SSRPage({ dateTime }: SSRPageProps) {
  return <main>{dateTime}</main>;
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip");

  return {
    props: { dateTime: res.data.datetime },
  };
};

interface SSRPageProps {
  abbreviation: string;
  client_ip: string;
  datetime: string;
  day_of_week: number;
  day_of_year: number;
  dst: boolean;
  dst_from: string;
  dst_offset: number;
  dst_until: string;
  raw_offset: number;
  timezone: string;
  unixtime: number;
  utc_datetime: string;
  utc_offset: string;
  week_number: number;
}
```

Comment: I also don't see any `dateTime` in SSRPageProps.

Comment: Yes, datetime !== dateTime

Answer (score 1):

In your interface is defined `datetime` but you are referencing `dateTime`

```
interface SSRPageProps {
  abbreviation: string;
  client_ip: string;
- datetime: string;
+ dateTime: string;
  day_of_week: number;
  day_of_year: number;
  dst: boolean;
  dst_from: string;
  dst_offset: number;
  dst_until: string;
  raw_offset: number;
  timezone: string;
  unixtime: number;
  utc_datetime: string;
  utc_offset: string;
  week_number: number;
}
```